# How to create advanced GTK TreeViews

Tags: treeview, gtk, pygtk

I need to build some not trivial Gtk TreeViews. I'd like to make something similar to the TreeViews used by the email client Geary ([this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/geary-0.4-screenshot-1024x558.jpg) is a screenshot).

My questions are:

1) The first column of Geary have some rows, but those that have children don't behave like the other rows but behave like a Gtk Expander (that is, if clicked won't be selected but will expand/collapse its node). How can I make this?

2) In the first column there are also some rows containing a number inside a rounded wrapper, I thought that I could make this easly with CSS but I'm unable to select that specific cell containing the number. How can I obtain a similar effect?

3) The second column of Geary contains some fairly complicated rows, basically they contain multiple rows of text. How can I create something similar? Do I need to create a custom Gtk CellRenderer? If yes, how do I do it exactly?

4) Is it possible to easily have rows in a TreeView containing Gtk Boxes and other widgets?

Ps. I'm using PyGTK.

Thank you.

Comment: The screenshot isn't accessible so I'm not sure what treeview you mean, but Geary does have e.g. custom CellRenderers. Since Geary is open source, I would suggest you read the source code (should be useful even if it's not the same language): https://git.gnome.org/browse/geary/tree/src/client

Comment: @jku I've mirrored the image [here](http://oi58.tinypic.com/20fakok.jpg). I've already tried this, but I don't have a good understanding of Vala, and in general the whole program is too giant for me.

Comment: A 20sec look into the directory tells me that geary uses a custom cell renderer. https://git.gnome.org/browse/geary/tree/src/client/conversation-list Maybe have a look at it yourself - or at least **try**